# Laravel Eloquent Select CASE?

Tags: sql, select, laravel, case, eloquent

Is there anyone with experience in PHP & Laravel Eloquent who can help me resolve this statement? I'm trying to inject a CASE... WHEN.. END... inside a raw() method. It seemed like it was completely ignored. The existing documentation hasn't been . I've tried several different things to no prevail. I'm trying to pull this off:

```
SELECT shares.id, ..., 
   CASE WHEN users.id = <CurrentUser> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_user, 
   ...
FROM <table>
...
```

The source code is below:

```
$shares = Share::where('shares.status', '=', SHARE_STATUS_APPROVED)
                    ->where('shares.deleted', '=', '0')
                    ->where('locations.lat', '<=', $nelat)
                    ->where('locations.lat', '>=', $swlat)
                    ->where('locations.lng', '>=', $nelng)
                    ->where('locations.lng', '<=',  $swlng)
                    ->where('users.id', '=',  $user)
                    ->orWhere('shares.connected_user_id', '=',  $user)
                    ->join('users', 'shares.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'users.location_id')
                    ->join('provinces', 'provinces.id', '=', 'locations.province_id')
                    ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'locations.country_id')
                    ->select('shares.id AS share_id', 'users.id AS user_id', 'shares.connected_user_id', 'shares.original_language_id', 'shares.image',
                        'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.email',
                        'locations.city', 'provinces.name', 'countries.code',
                        'locations.lat', 'locations.lng',
                        'shares.created_at')
                    ->raw('(CASE WHEN users.id = ' . $user . ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS is_user')
                    ->orderBy('shares.created_at', 'desc')
                    ->orderBy('users.id', 'asc')
                    ->orderBy('shares.connected_user_id', 'asc')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: In modern code, the answer is `->selectRaw('CASE WHEN users.id=? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END', [$user])`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Move your `raw()` call inside the `SELECT` statement:

```
->select('shares.id AS share_id', 'users.id AS user_id', 'shares.connected_user_id',    
  'shares.original_language_id', 'shares.image',
  'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.email',
  'locations.city', 'provinces.name', 'countries.code',
  'locations.lat', 'locations.lng',
  'shares.created_at',
  DB::raw('(CASE WHEN users.id = ' . $user . ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS is_user')
  )
->orderBy('shares.created_at', 'desc')
```

From: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Nice and very useful

Comment: If you are using array to select the fields push the raw query to that array and use it example:                                                                                  
          array_push($columnArr, DB::raw("(CASE WHEN isActive = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END) as Active_Status")); And then write                   
         DB::table($table) ->select($columnArr)

Comment: How can we set a where condition with CASE statements? Kindly suggest. Thanks

Comment: `'(CASE WHEN users.id = ' . $user . ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS is_user'` looks like you could do an SQL injection ...

Answer (score 16):

Alternatively you can use `selectRaw` instead.

```
->selectRaw("shares.id AS share_id, users.id AS user_id , 
    shares.connected_user_id ,    
      shares.original_language_id, shares.image,
      users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email,
      locations.city, provinces.name, countries.code,
      locations.lat, locations.lng,
      shares.created_at,
      (CASE WHEN users.id = {$user} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS is_user)")
    ->orderBy('shares.created_at', 'desc')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just recently I have created a package that adds CASE support for Eloquent Query Builder. You can check it out here: https://github.com/aglipanci/laravel-eloquent-case

Using the package you can do this:

```
use App\Models\Invoice;
use AgliPanci\LaravelCase\Query\CaseBuilder;

$invoices = Invoice::query()
            ->case(function (CaseBuilder $case) {
                $case->when('balance', '<', 0)->then('Overpaid')
                    ->when('balance', 0)->then('Paid')
                    ->else('Balance Due');
            }, 'payment_status')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package I've written [Laravel Query Enrich](https://github.com/SiavashBamshadnia/Laravel-Query-Enrich/).

```php
use sbamtr\LaravelQueryEnrich\QE;
use function sbamtr\LaravelQueryEnrich\c;

$books = Book::select(
    'id',
    'name',
    'price',
    QE::case()
        ->when(c('price'), '>', 100)->then('expensive')
        ->when(QE::condition(50, '<', c('price')), QE::condition(c('price'), '<=', 100))->then('moderate')
        ->else('affordable')
        ->as('price_category')
)->get();
```

Check out this page for the documentation you need:

https://laravel-query-enrich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/QE/Advanced/case/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).