# Sort query results alphabetically, but exclude "the" in sorting?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say I have a Laravel 4 application. Let's also say I have a populated Movies table.

This:

```
$movies = Movie::orderBy('title', 'ASC')->get();
```

Returns this:

```
Braveheart
Silent Hill
The Big Lebowski
Waterworld
```

What I'd like though, is to ignore "the" in the sort to return this:

```
The Big Lewbowski
Braveheart
Silent Hill
Waterworld
```

Is there anything inside Laravel that could make this easy? How would you approach this? Do I need to write a custom SQL query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Hello good day to you**

Store the results in an array. 
Loop through the array and remove all the 'The'.

Something like this:

```
$str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
if(substr($str, 0, 4) = 'The ')
{
    $str2 = substr($str, 4); // "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
}
```

Create a new array from the stuff above.

Then do something like this:

```
<?php

$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
sort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}
?>
```

This will sort them alphabetically:

```
fruits[0] = apple
fruits[1] = banana
fruits[2] = lemon
fruits[3] = orange
```

Thats it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the syntax of laravel 4 but in mysql query you can use `REPLACE`

```
REPLACE(column, 'search', 'replace')

SELECT * FROM `movies` ORDER BY  REPLACE(`title`, 'The', '')
```

For laravel 4 hope so it works but not sure

```
$movies = Movie::orderBy("REPLACE(`title`, 'The', '')", "ASC")->get();
```

[**REPLACE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

**EDIT** Searching "The" only in starting of string you can use `CASE` and `LEFT` to check appearence of "The"

```
 SELECT * FROM `movies` ORDER BY 
 CASE WHEN LEFT(`title`,4) ='The ' 
 THEN REPLACE(`title`, 'The ', '') 
 ELSE `title`
 END

$movies = Movie::orderBy("CASE WHEN LEFT(`title`,4) ='The ' 
 THEN REPLACE(`title`, 'The ', '') 
 ELSE `title`
 END", "ASC")->get();
```

Comment: It will remove all that matches. Even when the The is in the middle. So not good!

Comment: @Netbulae that doesn't matter too much for ordering just slightly matter if the appears between the string or at end

Answer (score 1):

I also do not know anything about Laravel, but this query may do what you want:

```
SELECT title
FROM movies 
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN SUBSTRING(title FROM 1 FOR 4) = 'The '
       THEN SUBSTRING(title,5) 
       ELSE title 
    END DESC
```

The other answer referring to the `REPLACE` function might also be good enough, but note `REPLACE` will replace all occurrences of the target string (for example "Gone With The Wind" would be changed.

Comment: Laravel doesnt need that stuff. It is intelligent and has one of the most advanced ORM's in PHP world called Eloquent. Checkl it out and say goodby to RAW queries.

Comment: @Netbulae how would you write this exact query with Laravel Eloquent?

Comment: You would put the case inside a select statement. A similar question has been answered here: [Laravel eloquent select case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092112/laravel-eloquent-select-case)