# Laravel where if statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I came to a problem with select from DB.
Basically what I am trying to achieve is:
I have a table with 3 columns

```
type | number | date
```

I need to do where based on column (type)

```
If(type = 1) then where number > 1 else where date today()
```

So if the type is equal to 1 then apply where to number else apply where to date. It is possible to do such a thing? And it is possible to do it with Laravel Eloquent?
Thank you.

The original query and datatype are:
`type = string number = integer date = timestamp (Y-m-d H:i:s)`

Query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE CASE WHEN type = days THEN date > now() ELSE number > 0 END
```

Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE banners (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  type varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  number int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  finish_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Solution that worked:

```
select * from `banners` 
where `banners`.`block_id` = 1 and `banners`.`block_id` is not null 
and IF (`type` = 'days', `finish_at` > now(), `number` > 0)
```

Laravel Way:

```
ParentModel::banners()->whereRaw("IF (`type` = 'days', `finish_at` > now(), `number` > 0)")->get();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use it like as

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE IF (`type` = 1, `number` > 1,`date` = today())
```

Using Laravel Eloquent you can use it like as

```
ModelName::whereRaw('IF (`type` = 1, `number` > 1,`date` = today())')->get();
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; `WHERE IF (type = days, finish_at > now() ,left > 0)' at line 3`

Comment: What is `days` over here ? You didn't specified it within your question

Comment: This is my data, type is a string, if accepts only integers?

Comment: Please specify your conditions clearly. What you want to achieve and what variables you're using over here also post the original error that you were getting over here

Comment: Updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is `type = days` over here

Comment: days is a value in type column, type value can be days or views.

Comment: So if type value is equal to days then check date column else check number column

Comment: Try as `type = 'days',`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE IF (type = 'days', finish_at > now() ,number > 0)` right syntax to use near '> 0)' at line 2

Comment: Post your table schema

Comment: had to add ` to columns name and worked like a charm

Comment: Its because you were using keywords which need to be escaped using `\``

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$query = SomeModel::where(function($query){
                            $query->where(function($query){
                                 $query->where('type',1)->where('number',1)
                             })
                            ->orWhere(function($query){
                                 $query->where('type',1)->where('date', today())
                             })
                         })
```

We use orWhere to solve this problem. And need a where wraps outside of orWhere to make it clear with another condition if need.

If you are using MySQL, try DB::raw and use CASE in WHERE:

[Laravel Eloquent Select CASE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092112/laravel-eloquent-select-case)

Comment: Good solution But I cant use OR I need exact where

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @PoWeR if you are using MySQL,  just take a look at DB raw queries . Using Case in where  may help. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092112/laravel-eloquent-select-case

Comment: MySQL I will take a look

Answer (score 3):

You should use `case` for this,

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE  CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN number > 1 ELSE date = today() END
```

Comment: This is what I need but MySQL gives error  You have an error in your SQL syntax;
`WHERE CASE WHEN type=days THEN finish_at > 1 ELSE left > 0 END`

Comment: @PoWeR will have a check and will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = '';//Date you want
$number = ''//Number you want
$field = ''//date or number
SomeModel::where($field, '=', $value)->where('type', '=', 'sometype');
```

You can use Eloquent of Laravel this way, its not necessary to do method chaining in single line.

EDIT: On the first i didnt got the question right.Now its fixed assume you will have dynamic "type" put it into use statement too.

EDIT 2: You can represent the field as literal according to if condition and then pass it to the where clause.

Comment: From where did you got variable $type? I think you didn't got the question