# Get row only if specific condition is true but it overrides previous condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to fetch all the rows whose `status` is not `a` or `b`.
But, if there are rows with two specific columns that are not null and `status` is `c`, then also fetch these rows.

This is how I tried to do it, but then it also fetches rows with `status` `b` where their `column_a` and `column_b` is not null

```
   select('*')
    ->whereNotIn('status',['a','b'])
    ->orWhere(function($query) {
          $query->where('column_a', "!=", null)
          ->where('column_b', "!=", null)
          ->where('status', "=", 'c');
    })
    ->get());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel where if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473053/laravel-where-if-statement)

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: @Rwd Using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
whereNotIn('status', ['a', 'b'])->where([['column_a', '!=', null], ['column', '!=', null], ['status', 'c']])->get();
```