# How can i convert complicated sql query to laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

This Work best. but i want to convert to laravel eloquent. can anyone one help me. i don't know how to use join in laravel.

```
DB::select("SELECT u.id,c.conversation_key,u.user_name,u.email
                                 FROM conversation c, user_profile u
                                 WHERE CASE 
                                 WHEN c.user_one = '8790'
                                 THEN c.user_two = u.id
                                 WHEN c.user_two = '8790'
                                 THEN c.user_one= u.id
                                 END 
                                 AND (
                                 c.user_one ='8790'
                                 OR c.user_two ='8790'
                                 )
                                 Order by c.conversation_key DESC Limit 20");
```

Comment: Here you have the full reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries. Try out something, maybe edit your question then with the laravel outcome if it does not work and we can look at it again.

Comment: hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092112/laravel-eloquent-select-case

Comment: can you solve me @JigarShah.

Comment: @DhruvRaval I'm not Jigar, but this is not a code-writing service. If it would be, it would become useless even in the short term because the real value of SO is in the answers to problems that more people can have, not only yours. Moreover, imho, there must be a good effort otherwise the quality would lower and SO would become more or less useless.

Comment: ok @reallynice. i wil try to solve my problem. using your or others reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted laravel Eloquen :

```
$userId = 8790;
$data['conversations'] = Conversation::selectRaw('user_profile.id, conversation_key, user_profile.first_name, user_profile.email')
            ->where(function ($q) use ($userId) {
                $q->where('user_one', $userId)
                    ->orWhere('user_two', $userId);
            })
            ->join('user_profile', function ($join) use ($userId) {
                $join->on('user_profile.id', '=', 'conversation.user_one')->where('conversation.user_one', '!=', $userId)
                    ->orOn('user_profile.id', '=', 'conversation.user_two')->where('conversation.user_two', '!=', $userId);
            })
            ->orderBy('conversation_key', 'DESC')
            ->take(20)
            ->get();
```