# How to use case statement in eloquent where condition

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I need to pick the dynamic column based on some condition and it has to be used in where condition.

```
    AuditLog::select('audit_log.id')
        ->join('columns_list', 'columns_list.id', '=', 'audit_log.interim_column_table_id')
        ->join('transactions', 'transactions.id', '=', 'audit_log.interim_transaction_id')
        ->whereRaw(columns_list.column_name = ?', ["p_gross"])
        ->latest('audit_log_transaction_level.created_at')
```

In the above query, I need to replace the ["p_gross"] with the following code

```
CASE
      WHEN transactions.transaction_type_id = 1 THEN 'p_gross'
      WHEN transactions.transaction_type_id = 2 THEN 's_gross'
END
```

here is the raw SQL for a better understanding

```
select audit_log.id
        from audit_log 
        join columns_list on columns_list.id = audit_log.interim_column_table_id
        join transactions on audit_log.interim_transaction_id = transactions.id
        where
        columns_list.column_name = CASE
                    WHEN transactions.tbi_transaction_type_id = 1 THEN 'p_gross'
                    WHEN transactions.tbi_transaction_type_id = 2 THEN 's_gross'
                    END 
       order by audit_log.created_at desc
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent Select CASE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092112/laravel-eloquent-select-case)

Comment: No @Peppermintology The answer suggests retrieving using the case statement. whereas I need it in where condition.

Comment: Surely the principle of applying a `case` statement in your condition is the same?

Comment: Yes, I do not have any other choice. The column needs to be picked dynamically.