# How to make mysql case then in laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this mysql query:

```
select
  case
    when country like '% usa %' then 'usa'
    when country like '% italy %' then 'italy'
    when country like '% china %' then 'china'
    when country like '% india %' then 'india'
  end as ccountry,
  count(*) as population
from
  (
    select concat(' ', country, ' ') as country
    from Table1
    where city = 'cityName'
  ) T
group by ccountry
```

i've already try using this query:

```
$subQuery = Table1::selectRaw("concat(' ', country, ' ') as country")
  ->where('city', 'cityName');
```

and this is the next query:

```
$query = DB::table(DB::raw('('.$subQuery->toSql().') as T')) 
  ->select(DB::raw("case
      when country like '% usa %' then 'usa'
      when country like '% italy %' then 'italy'
      when country like '% china %' then 'china'
      when country like '% india %' then 'india'
    end as ccountry"), DB::raw('count(*) as population'))
  ->groupBy('ccountry') 
  ->get();
```

And this is the error message:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

```
select
  case
    when country like '% usa %' then 'usa'
    when country like '% italy %' then 'italy'
    when country like '% china %' then 'china'
    when country like '% india %' then 'india'
  end as ccountry,
  count(*) as population
from
  (
    select concat(' ', country, ' ') as country
    from Table1
    where city = ?
  ) T
group by ccountry
```

i think, the problem is because the value of where city becomes a question mark (?)
please if anyone can help, I'm very grateful.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Probably not doable in Eloquent, but should be doable using the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries)

Comment: @brombeer yes i mean also use query builder, i've already try using the query builder, but not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092112/laravel-eloquent-select-case

Comment: "_but not working_" is very vague. Please [edit] your question and post the code you already have - even if it "doesn't work" - and also post any error you get and describe _what_ doesn't work

Comment: @brombeer u know why in the result query from subquery in where to be (?)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. In `concat(' ', level, ' ')` why did you replace `country` from your original query with `level`, is that intended?

Comment: @brombeer oh ya, sorry, i mean error exist because "where city = ?", the value of cityName changes to (?)
thats because i use toSql(), so how to solve this ya?

Comment: Maybe _not_ use `->toSql()`

Answer (score 1):

you can write `selectRaw('')` like this:

```
selectRaw('case 
   when country like '% usa %' then 'usa'
   when country like '% italy %' then 'italy'
   when country like '% china %' then 'china'
   when country like '% india %' then 'india'
end')
```